# Is it OK to use 'free' in a tax subtotal?

Tags: gui-design, copywriting, guidelines

we are designing a checkout page and in the subtotals area we have a breakout for tax, shipping and discounts.

We use the term 'free' rather than '0.00'.

So, for example:

```
Subtotal:     $140.00
Tax:          FREE
Shipping:     FREE
Savings:      ($4.50)
Total:        $135.50
```

**QUESTION: is it goofy to use the term 'free' for tax?** I'm tempted to keep this as-is for consistency, but was hoping to hear from the broader community.

If you have a better suggestion, we'd love to hear it!

Thanks,
Nancy

Comment: Note some things are taxed at a 0% rate or are zero rated so it might just be the particular items chosen

Answer (score 7):

It makes perfect sense for shipping, as that's a benefit you are providing your customer.

But also listing it for taxes seems to dilute the benefit of the term for shipping--after all, not charging taxes is not a benefit you are directly providing the customer (it's something the customer's local government is doing).

I'd suggest sticking with numbers ($0.00). (BTW, if you are in the US, note that sales tax laws for online purchases are likely going to be changing soon).

Comment: We just heard about the pending changes! Thanks for the heads up.

You make a good point about the benefit of free shipping... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think "None" would be a better choice. "Free" indicates that you are covering tax like a gift - as would be used for shipping. "None" stands out more than a number - which can be more easily misread - and gets people excited. No tax!

Comment: Thanks, I agree that text seems to stand out more - and I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would go with 0$ and mention free besides it.

```
Subtotal:     $140.00
Tax:           $0.00   - FREE 
Shipping:      $0.00   - FREE
Savings:      ($4.50)
Total:        $135.50
```

The reason being, it is easier for someone to read $0.00 in a bill while looking at the numbers. You can still **mention FREE besides the $0.00 to reinforce** the fact that they are getting something for Free. Maybe even mention that it is because they are valued customer to **make them feel extra-special**.

```
Shipping:      $0.00   - FREE for Premium Customer
```

Comment: I wouldn't mention that they are not paying taxes because they are special, as that's a lie. They are not paying taxes due to local tax regulations.